# Azure ApiM unable to create jwt token validation policy with RSA certificate

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

According to documentation in Azure API Management it is possible to create JWT token validation policy using certificate id of RSA certificate previously uploaded to APIM.

I am trying to build such policy as described in the docs, and it is saved without errors, but when I open the policy definition again, key element is always empty, without the certificate-id attribute I set earlier.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#token-validation-with-rsa-certificate

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can also reproduce your issue on my side, after configuration and come back, the policy will be like below.

[image]

It looks should be a bug in UI, because if you get the policy with PowerShell [`Get-AzApiManagementPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/get-azapimanagementpolicy?view=azps-4.8.0#example-3--get-the-api-scope-policy) or REST API - [`Api Policy - Get`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/apipolicy/get) directly, we can get the value. So I think the policy should be applied, just ignore it and go on.

**Powershell:**

```
$ApiMgmtContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "groupname" -ServiceName "joyapim"
Get-AzApiManagementPolicy -Context $ApiMgmtContext -ApiId 'echo-api'
```

[image]

**REST API:**

[image]