# Can I use JWK having modulus(n) and exponent(e) to validate JWT in Azure Api management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, apim

From validate-jwt policy reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validate-jwt-policy

```
<issuer-signing-keys>     

<key>Base64 encoded signing key | certificate-id="mycertificate" | n="modulus" e="exponent</key>

</issuer-signing-keys>
```

It says, I can use mod(n) and exponent(e) to validate JWT. I tried it but it in inbound policy, but it says that it is **not valid base64 string**. How to use jwk having n and e parameters to validate JWT?

When I convert JWT into public key(from external source) and save it to named value. Policy is getting saved but not saving while using n and e parameters of JWK.
If there is way to convert JWK to base64 string in APIM, that will also work.

Inbound policy:

```
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized">
<issuer-signing-keys>
     <key> n = {{n}} e = {{e}}</key>
</issuer-signing-keys>
</validate-jwt>
```

**Update:**
The policy works only when I put modulus(n) and exponent(e) as constant OR save constants in named value and then use them like below

```
<key n = "{{n}}" e = "{{e}}"/>
```

But I need to extract n, e from another header and then validate JWT. Is it possible using jwt-validate? Like below,

```
<issuer-signing-keys>
   <key n= "@(Context.variables["mod"])" e= "@(Context.variables["exponent"])" />
</issuer-signing-keys>
```

Comment: can you share your whole policy please

Comment: what kind of validation you are using here like Azure AD or anything else?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin Added code inside <inbound> tag.
Error: Error in element 'validate-jwt' on line 43, column 10: value is not a valid base64 string.

Comment: can you check this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65232407/azure-apim-unable-to-create-jwt-token-validation-policy-with-rsa-certificate?rq=1

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin The above question helped me putting modulus and Exponent in right format. Thanks for help!!